# How can I add more than one continuous color scale in a single px.scatter plot?

Tags: python, plotly-express

I currently am trying to make a bubble plot that is generated from the following code. An example of the bubble plot that is produced is also included.

```
height = (df['terms'].nunique()*20)+100
fig = px.scatter(df, x='group', y='terms', size='-log10(pvalue)', 
                 color='health_status', height=height, width=1500, 
                 color_discrete_map={'healthy': 'red', 'sick':'blue'})
iplot(fig)
```

[image: bubbleplot_example]

Now, although I have the size of the markers on the plot determined by the value of -log10(pvalue), I also want to have the color of the markers to be determined by the -log10(pvalue). However, I want to distinguish between healthy and sick groups in that the healthy groups would have a continuous color scale going from light to dark red, while the sick groups would have a continuous color scale going from light to dark blue (also in proportion to the value of -log10(pvalue)). I have been trying to figure out how to integrate these two different continuous color scales into the plot, but I have been having no luck so far. It seems like you can only use one continuous color plot per plot as far as I can tell, but I'm not sure. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Update**:

Here is a small snippet of the input data I am using to create the plot (separated by tabs):

```
terms   group   health_status   pvalue  -LOG10(pvalue)
innate immune response in mucosa    Group A healthy healthy 0.001312593 2.881869847
low-density lipoprotein particle remodeling Group A healthy healthy 0.004084727 2.388836964
nucleosome assembly Group A healthy healthy 0.005324106 2.273753336
antimicrobial humoral immune response mediated by antimicrobial peptide Group B healthy healthy 0.005932275 2.226778741
intermediate filament organization  Group B healthy healthy 0.005932275 2.226778741
defense response to bacterium   Group B healthy healthy 0.005932275 2.226778741
leukocyte migration involved in inflammatory response   Group B healthy healthy 0.015600119 1.806872092
defense response to Gram-negative bacterium Group B healthy healthy 0.015600119 1.806872092
keratinization  Group C healthy healthy 0.018984856 1.721592692
Golgi apparatus mannose trimming    Group C healthy healthy 0.018984856 1.721592692
sequestering of zinc ion    Group C healthy healthy 0.018984856 1.721592692
chylomicron remnant clearance   Group A sick    sick    0.018984856 1.721592692
neutrophil aggregation  Group A sick    sick    0.018984856 1.721592692
protein localization to CENP-A containing chromatin Group A sick    sick    0.018984856 1.721592692
negative regulation of lipid biosynthetic process   Group B sick    sick    0.018984856 1.721592692
antibacterial humoral response  Group B sick    sick    0.022844656 1.641215378
positive regulation of cell growth  Group B sick    sick    0.023998364 1.619818356
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide data that can reproduce the graphs in the question? I would be a shortcut to solving your problem if I could do that.

Comment: @r-beginners check my update. Let me know if you need any additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply scale in express, a numerical sequence must be set to a color. We also need to separate the color scale in two category variables, so we need to deal with this in the graph object. Draw a scatter plot with the data frame extracted by health status. Here, we need to devise the x-axis because the categorical variables on the x-axis are the same. I change the group column to category type and add a new column for that category value. at the second category, I add 0.5 to the x-axis scale to shift the x-axis. the x-axis text is set manually by 5 since there are 5 categories.

```
df['group_cd'] = df['group'].astype('category').cat.codes
df.head()
terms   group   health_status   pvalue  -LOG10(pvalue)  group_cd
0   innate immune response in mucosa    Group A     healthy healthy     0.001313    2.881870    0
1   low-density lipoprotein particle remodeling     Group A     healthy healthy     0.004085    2.388837    0
2   nucleosome assembly     Group A     healthy healthy     0.005324    2.273753    0
3   antimicrobial humoral immune response mediated...   Group B     healthy healthy     0.005932    2.226779    1
4   intermediate filament organization  Group B     healthy healthy     0.005932    2.226779    1

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

for status, scale in zip(df['health_status'].unique(), ['Blues','Reds']):
    dff = df.query('health_status == @status')
    if status == 'sick sick':
        group = dff['group_cd']+0.5
    else:
        group = dff['group_cd']
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='markers',
                             x=group,#dff['group_cd'],
                             y=dff['terms'],
                             marker=dict(
                                 size=dff['-LOG10(pvalue)']*10,
                                 color=dff['-LOG10(pvalue)'],
                                 colorscale=scale,
                                 showscale=False
                                        ),
                             showlegend=True,
                             name=status
                            ))

fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=[0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2], ticktext=['Group A healthy','Group A Sick','Group B healthy','Group B Sick','Group C healthy'])
fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This has definitely helped me a lot, however, I should note that my x axis categories are not fixed to only Group A healthy/sick, Group B healthy/sick, etc... there is actually up to 5 groups, but not all of them show up in the x axis for each of the plots that I'm trying to make. I have been trying to get the x axis to be properly formatted (I also need the sick groups on the right and healthy groups on the left), but I have so far not been successful. How can we make the code more generalized for different groups?

Comment: Have you tried my code with the data in your question, you can see the structure better if you disable the x-axis scale setting section. What is not working?

Comment: I have indeed commented out the `fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=[0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2], ticktext=['Group A healthy','Group A Sick','Group B healthy','Group B Sick','Group C healthy'])` and I can see that when that line is not active, the x axis looks like numbers incrementing by 0.5. But the markers are not aligned to the x axis, and furthermore, the blue healthy markers are sometimes mixed in with red sick markers, when they should be separate. I have very carefully copied your code so I'm not sure what exactly the error is.

Comment: Try to add the current most recent code (using the data in your question) and the output diagram to your question.

Comment: ok I got it working, I did make some modifications to your code though. I first set the for loop to only loop around `df['health_status'].unique()`, and if the status was equal to `healthy`, then `scales` was set to `Reds` (else it was set to `Blues`). Furthermore, I set the x value in the scatter plot to `dff['group_health_status']`, which is a column I made that concatenates the values in the columns `group` and `health_status`. I also removed the column `group_cd`. Thanks so much for your guidance!